# Не могу подключиться к AWS Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

Не могу подключиться к своему AWS Ubuntu инстансу через Putty, все было нормально, подключался, security group настроен, порт 22 SSH на входящие открыт.
Запустил Nginxs, после этого, не могу подключиться через Putty,
если набираю IP в браузере, вижу, что nginxs работает, но IP не пингуется...

Answer (score 1):

ssh, http и ping используют разные протоколы и порты, если работает пинг, то совсем не обязательно будет работать ssh и наоборот.
Потенциальные причины это security group или NACL. Большая вероятность того, что это все же SG.
Проще всего для проверки разрешить все порты и протоколы в SG и посмотреть результат.